# What is "flag weight", as displayed on my profile?

Tags: support

To my surprise, this number doesn't seem to be covered in the FAQ, and a search here on meta didn't give me an answer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in [What is flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) the flag weight is a number associated with your flags, which is incremented every time your flags are marked helpful, and decremented every time your flags are declined.
The purpose of that number is to give more importance to the flags done from who has a history of helpful flags. In the page the moderators use to see all the flags (flags that don't use a custom reason are visible to 10k users, who don't know who flagged the post), the flags are ordered basing on the flag weight for who flagged a post/comment (flags on comments are visible only to moderators): When the flag weight is higher, the flag is show before another flag done by a user with a lower flag weight.

Every time your flag is considered helpful, your flag weight is increased by 10; every time your flag is declined, your flag weight is decreased of 10. The increment is changed when your flag weight is at least 500; in that case, the increment is different, and your flag weight is incremented less than 10 for every helpful flag. The decrement is still 10, when your flag is declined.

There are some cases where a flag is not marked helpful, and you don't get any decrement of your flag weight. This happens when your flag is flagged as invalid from another user. As I said before, 10k users can see part of the flags, and they can flag it as invalid; in this case, the flag is disputed, and you don't get any flag weight lose.

[image: screenshot]

You get a badge if your flag weight reaches 500, and another badge when it reaches 749.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Recently, the flag weight has been replaced from the number of useful flags, and the requirements for the related flags have been changed.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Users who badge basing on the old requirements still have the badge.